# WPF C# XML resources in subfolder not getting built

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, resources

Currently in my project directory I have a folder called "Data" and in it I have two XML files that I use in my WPF application. I have set the XML files as "Resource" and the "Copy to Output Directory" option to "Copy Always". However, the following code throws a DirectoryNotFoundException because the files aren't being copied over to bin\debug when I build my application.

`return new Game(XDocument.Load("Data/Game.xml").Root);`

How do I make it so that everytime I build the files are moved over without having to do it manually everytime I change my XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set 'Build Action' to **None**
When you set Build Action to **Resource** - it means, that VS will automatically pack this file into assembly as embedded resource. More about [Resource Files on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx#Resource_Files)

And when 'Build Action' is **None** - Studio has nothing else to do, but to follow "Copy to Output Directory" command.

Comment: That worked thank you. I'm new to WPF might I ask why None works but Resource doesn't?

Comment: Yes, you can) Updated my answer with that info.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And that's better english than half the people on black ops =P